# $|a_n|$ is diverging. Prove $a_n$ has a subsequence converging to a finite limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$|a_n|$ is diverging.
How do you prove $a_n$ (without absolute value) has a subsequence converging to a finite limit?

I know that if a sequence has two subsequences converging to different numbers, then the sequence is diverging. May I use the opposite lemma?

**EDIT:**
The sequence $|a_n|$ doesn't diverging to $\infty$. So you may say the sequence has no limit.

Comment: thats false, take $a_n$ positives to begin with.

Comment: With the edit it still is false: $\;a_n=(-1)^nn\;$

Comment: Your example is wrong because $|a_n|$ can't diverge to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true: Take the sequence $$a_n = n$$ Then every subsequence diverges.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: @DanielGagnon So is your sequence divergent, but bounded? Are you familiar with the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Comment: Let me interpret what you're saying: if the sequence has no limit and doesn't diverge to $\infty$ then it must be bounded, and therefore must have a subsequence with a finite limit according to BW Theorem. Right?

Comment: @DanielGagnon If by "doesn't diverge to $\infty$" you mean that it's bounded, then yes.

Comment: wonderful, Thanks a lot!

Comment: If a sequence doesn't converge (neither to a finite number nor infinity) it must be bounded. right?

Comment: @DanielGagnon No, as DonAntonio's counterexample shows.

Comment: OK, but for the sequence $|a_n|$ (Notice the absolute value) it must be bounded, if doesn't converge to infinity/finite number.

Comment: @Daniel: No! It can be unbounded, but still not converge to infinity. For instance, if $a_{2n} = n$ but $a_{2n+1} = 1$.